# Geometry Nodes into Animation

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface

My goal: I want a smooth interpolation of the vertices to the new location due to subdivision-surface modifier and export it to unity.

I created a **Geometry Node** with just a Subdivision Surface in it for a normal cube.
With the Edge-Crease moving from 1 to 0 i added on each side keyframes. Now i have a smooth transition from a normal cube to the first iteration of it.

But this is not being saved as an animation...
This id like to move into an animation in order to export the cube + animation into unity.

The Problem with making keyframes into the modifier of subdivision-surface makes the animation jump from Cube into the 1. Iteration without a smooth transitioning

Comment: Hi Kat, please edit the question and add more detail. Like, what steps you are taking to export the animation and the file format used.